# Convert XML to dataframe using XML2 -- SDMX case

Tags: r, xml, xml-parsing, xml2

Please have a look at the reprex in this question.
SDMX is a data model for disseminating statistical data and there are tools in Python and R to handle it. SDMX is usually given as an XML file (recently also as a JSON file).
I can handle the simple example given in the url in the reprex with a dedicated library, but I would like to understand what is going on, so I would like to reproduce the final result using xml2 and... here is where I bang my head against the wall.

The reason is that in the near future I may have to handle complex XML files which are close to an SDMX, but not exactly identical, which means I need to be able to do this by hand.
Any suggestion is appreciated.
Thanks

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(xml2)
library(rsdmx)


url <- "https://stats.oecd.org/restsdmx/sdmx.ashx/GetData/FDIINDEX/AUT+BEL.4+5+8+9+14.V.INDEX/all?startTime=1997&endTime=2019"


##Very easy if I resort to a dedicated library

sdmx <- readSDMX(url, isURL = T)
stats <- as_tibble(sdmx)  ## and I have my nice tibble

print(stats)
#> # A tibble: 130 x 7
#>    LOCATION SECTOR RESTYPE SERIES TIME_FORMAT obsTime obsValue
#>    <chr>    <chr>  <chr>   <chr>  <chr>       <chr>      <dbl>
#>  1 AUT      4      V       INDEX  P1Y         1997           0
#>  2 AUT      4      V       INDEX  P1Y         2003           0
#>  3 AUT      4      V       INDEX  P1Y         2006           0
#>  4 AUT      4      V       INDEX  P1Y         2010           0
#>  5 AUT      4      V       INDEX  P1Y         2011           0
#>  6 AUT      4      V       INDEX  P1Y         2012           0
#>  7 AUT      4      V       INDEX  P1Y         2013           0
#>  8 AUT      4      V       INDEX  P1Y         2014           0
#>  9 AUT      4      V       INDEX  P1Y         2015           0
#> 10 AUT      4      V       INDEX  P1Y         2016           0
#> # … with 120 more rows


xmlobj <- read_xml(url)

## and then I do not know how to proceed...
```

<sup>Created on 2020-09-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: You can read the source code of these functions on github: [readSDMX](https://github.com/opensdmx/rsdmx/blob/451482bfcd5700505d0a5b36f9bb574f6fee2a1a/R/readSDMX.R) and [as.data.frame.SDMXMessageGroup](https://github.com/opensdmx/rsdmx/blob/78134a2231dec60314c60f22c3c76851fa2a1ab8/R/SDMXMessageGroup-methods.R#L68) / [as.data.frame.SDMXGenericData](https://github.com/opensdmx/rsdmx/blob/78134a2231dec60314c60f22c3c76851fa2a1ab8/R/SDMXGenericData-methods.R#L21) which is called by `as_tibble`.

Comment: Correct. I will take a good look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should learn about XPath. I give the comment in the code to help you understand:

```
library(xml2)
url <- "https://stats.oecd.org/restsdmx/sdmx.ashx/GetData/FDIINDEX/AUT+BEL.4+5+8+9+14.V.INDEX/all?startTime=1997&endTime=2019"
series <- read_xml(url) %>% xml_ns_strip() %>% xml_find_all("//DataSet/Series") # find all Series nodes
# note that the easiest way to read nodes in this file is to remove the namespaces by xml_ns_strip()
data <- 
  purrr::map_dfr(
    series,
    function(x) {
      data.frame(
        LOCATION = x %>% xml_find_first(".//Value[@concept='LOCATION']") %>% xml_attr("value"), # for each Series node, get the first Value node has 'concept' attribute is 'LOCATION' and extract the 'value' attribute value
        SECTOR = x %>% xml_find_first(".//Value[@concept='SECTOR']") %>% xml_attr("value"),
        RESTYPE = x %>% xml_find_first(".//Value[@concept='RESTYPE']") %>% xml_attr("value"),
        SERIES = x %>% xml_find_first(".//Value[@concept='SERIES']") %>% xml_attr("value"),
        TIME_FORMAT = x %>% xml_find_first(".//Value[@concept='TIME_FORMAT']") %>% xml_attr("value"),
        data.frame(
          Time = x %>% xml_find_all(".//Obs/Time") %>% xml_text(trim = TRUE) %>% as.integer(),
          ObsValue = x %>% xml_find_all(".//Obs/ObsValue") %>% xml_attr("value") %>% as.numeric()
        )
      ) 
    }
    )
```